# Chrome extension to translate selected text on keyboard shortcut press

Tags: gratis, chrome, translation

I am looking for a Chrome extension that translates the selected text into a selectable language after pressing a shortcut.

It should:

- be free
- auto detect the selected text's language
- ask me which language I want it to translate to, show me it in an easy to read manner
- activate via a shortcut that is user definable

Comment: Google translate has an extension that can be configured to translate text as soon as you select it. It does not support keyboard shortcuts though

Comment: @Timmy could you link to that please, I'll see how it works

Comment: You can find it [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)

Comment: @Timmy  I see... It is a good option, and would be useful for future users, so you might want to add this as an answer, but I won't be able to accept it, as *I* need a short cut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google translate has an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) that translates text selection.

- It is free
- Auto detects the selected language language
- Offers the choice of destination language in the extension options
- Does not support keyboard shortcuts, but it can be configured to automatically pop-out either a window with the translation, or a clickable icon.

[image]

---

**Edit**:

You can find a *Google Translate* entry in the context menu as indicated in the comment by Steve. This enables the use of an [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/) command to bind a hotkey to it. It would be something like

```
#t::Send {AppsKey}g
```

Comment: You can use the translate extension from the keyboard by pressing the context menu button, (usually next to the right CTRL button), and then using the cursor keys - tested on Win & KDE.

Comment: @SteveBarnes True, and then maybe bind that sequence into a hotkey using AHK!

Comment: @Timmy that's a good idea! I will try that soon. +1 for good suggestion.

Comment: @ṧнʊß I've edited the answer with the corresponding command