# A Chrome extension to translate text while writing?

Tags: chrome, translation

**Scenario:**

Imagining you are composing text in an online editor, be it a blog post, a journal entry or a question on Stack Exchange. You are composing the text in your non-native language and at point use a word of your native language because you don't know it in your non-native language.

**Request:**

I am looking for a Chrome extension that can easily help me translate this word into the non-native destination language (i.e. in most cases this is English) while writing.

**Workflow:**

I imagine this extension to allow me to highlight the word I need to translate and upon pressing a button or trigger, translates the word for me.

Comment: After answering I found [this question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/13392/26070) as a potential dupe target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google Translate plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb) can do this.

> UPDATE (v.2.0): Now you can highlight or right-click a text and translate it vs. translate the entire page. You can also change extension options to automatically show translation every time you highlight text.